# Cantidad de veces que se repite un número de un array en PHP

Tags: php, array, random

Buen día, quisiera saber como mostrar con un "+" las veces que se repite cada numero de un array en PHP, solo me falta eso.

Enunciado del ejercicio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$randomArry = array();
$max_num = 100;

for($x=0;$x<$max_num;$x++){
 $rango = rand(1,50);
 array_push($randomArry,$rango);}


print_r("<pre>");
print_r($randomArry);
print_r("</pre>");

$repetidas = array_count_values($randomArry);
print_r("<pre>");
print_r($repetidas);
print_r("/<pre>");

for($i=0;$i<$max_num;$i++) {
  echo $randomArry[$i].": ".$repetidas[$randomArry[$i]]."<br>";}
```

Comment: Hola Arnold, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código como texto? Así es mas fácil responder, ya que podemos copiar y modificarlo a gusto. De paso te recomiendo realizar el [tour] y ganar tu primer medalla.

Comment: Por favor agrega el código como texto no como imagen, para que podamos copiarlo, probarlo y apoyarte

Comment: Listo ya lo edite. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: Esa función es propia de PHP, https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: Prueba con `str_pad('', $repetidas[$i], '+')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He corregido el problema con la respuesta anterior.
Además he reemplazado el array automático, con uno fijo para temas de prueba.
Basta con quitar la asignación manual, para hacerlo automático.

El problema anterior, está mencionado en los comentarios, no aparecen los números sin repeticiones.

Entonces el cambio hecho, es el sgte:

```
<?php
// Generamos un array con valores aleatorios
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $array[] = random_int(0, 50);
}
//Sustituimos por un ejemplo fijo. 
// Acá tenemos el numero 2, 2 veces, y el numero 6, 3 veces.
$array = [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8];
echo "pos | valor </br>";
$counter = array_count_values($array); //Obtenemos repetidos
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) { //Recorremos el arreglo para ver los valores
    $valor1 = $array[$i];
    echo ($i+1) . " (" . $valor1 . ")</br>";
}
echo "</br></br>";
//Procedemos a realizar el proceso
echo "valor | repeticiones </br>";
for ($x = 0; $x < count($array); $x++) {
    if (array_key_exists($x, $counter)) {
        if (in_array($counter[$x], $array)) {
            $valor2 = $counter[$x];
            echo $x . " (" . $valor2 . ")" . ": " . str_pad('', $valor2, '+') . "</br>";
        }
    }else{
        $min = min($array);
        $max = max($array);
        if($x >= $min && $x <= $max){
            echo $x." (0):</br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias a todos por su consejos.

Answer (score 1):

Una vez que ya tienes las posiciones repetidas, solo te queda ordenarlas y recorrerlas para pintarlas en pantalla.

Ejemplo:

```php
<?php

// Generamos un array con valores aleatorios
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){
    $array[] = random_int(0, 50);
}


// Obtenemos las repeticiones
$counter = array_count_values($array);

// ordenamos las repeticiones
ksort($counter);

// Recorremos las repeticiones
foreach($counter as $key => $value) {
    // pintamos en pantalla añadiendo + segun la cantidad de repeticiones
    echo $key . str_pad('', $value, '+') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Resultado de ejemplo**

```
1: ++
3: ++
4: +++++
5: +++
6: +
7: +++
8: ++
9: ++
10: ++
11: +++
12: +++
13: ++
14: ++
15: ++++
16: ++++
18: ++++
19: +++
20: ++
21: +
23: ++
24: ++
25: ++
26: +
27: ++
28: ++
29: ++
30: +
31: ++++
33: +
34: +
35: ++
36: ++
37: ++++
38: ++
39: ++
40: +
41: +
42: +
44: +++
45: ++++
46: +
47: ++
48: +++
50: ++
```

Si queremos lista los números de 0 al 50 por ejemplo, mostrandolos aún que no hayan aparecido necesitamos recorrerlos.

Ejemplo:

```php
<?php

// Generamos un array con valores aleatorios
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $array[] = random_int(0, 50);
}


// Obtenemos las repeticiones
$counter = array_count_values($array);

// ordenamos las repeticiones
// ksort($counter); Ya no necesitamos ordenar

// Recorremos el rango de valores para poder pintarlos todos
foreach(range(0, 50) as $value) {
    // Inicializamos el total a 0
    $total = 0;
    //  Comprobamos si el número existe en el contador
    if (isset($counter[$value])) {
        // Si existe asignamos el valor al total
        $total = $counter[$value];
    }

    // pintamos en pantalla añadiendo + segun la cantidad de repeticiones
    echo $value . ': ' . str_pad('', $total, '+') . PHP_EOL;
}

/**
Resultado de ejemplo

0: +
1: +
2: +
3: +++
4: +++
5: 
6: ++++
7: 
8: +++
9: +
10: ++++
11: ++
12: 
13: ++
14: +++
15: +
16: +
17: +
18: +
19: ++++
20: ++
21: +++
22: ++++
23: +++
24: +
25: ++
26: +++
27: +
28: +
29: +
30: ++
31: ++
32: +
33: +++
34: +++
35: ++
36: +
37: ++
38: ++++
39: +
40: +++
41: 
42: ++
43: +
44: ++
45: +
46: +
47: ++
48: ++++
49: ++++
50: ++
*/
```

Documentación:

- [random_int](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.random-int)
- [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-count-values)
- [ksort](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ksort.php)
- [str_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-pad)

Comment: En el ejemplo de la pregunta se muestra 4 con cero; no pasa lo mismo en tu ejemplo con 17.

Comment: Eso es por que solo obtiene los repetidos al usar `array_count_values` Lo que puede hacer, es seguir el original array, y cuando el pintado sea uno de los repetidos, haga el segundo for, sino imprime lo no repetido, y en 0.

Comment: @sal agre un ejemplo si quieres mostrar todos los números del 0 al 50

Comment: @Excorpion Si utiliza el original tendrá el mismo problema por qué se rellena con valores aleatorios y puede haber números que no aparezcan.

Comment: Ya realice una respuesta solucionando ese mismo problema.

Comment: @Excorpion Lo acabo de ver, no me di cuenta, no obstante creo que liaste demasiado la cosa. Además tú ejemplo con un array aleatorio en que se debe contar las apariciones de los primeros 50 números naturales solo funcionaria si el valor máximo del los valores es 50, si se da la casualidad de que al generar los números aleatorios todos los números generados son >50 fallaría

Comment: bah... que raro... es como tu lo tienes... como dije, no solucione tus problemas... solo el problema mencionado arriba.

Comment: En el ejemplo que agregaste debería ser de 1 a 50.